# make public the object created by tcp socket

Tags: python, tcp

i am making a GUI application, the problem that i had is that i dont know how to access the object created by .accept(), i had seen a lot of tutorials but all of them do like console application, so i need to create in some how the socket object, i open the connection with a push button and other process send the data

```
from email import message
from fileinput import filename
from operator import truediv
import sys
from tkinter.tix import Tree
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
import tkinter
import tkinter.filedialog
import socket
import threading as th
from time import sleep
from tkinter import messagebox


from GUI import Ui_MainWindow, Ui_MainWindow
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *


TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)



def Stream():
    while True:
        while main_win.Transmit:
            f = open(main_win.filename, "r")
            x = len(f.readlines())
            while x>=main_win.Lastline:
                data=(f.readline(main_win.Lastline+1))
                main_win.Lastline=main_win.Lastline+1
                conn.send(data) #out of scope
            f.close()
            sleep(main_win.ui.doubleSpinBox.value())
    
    

T = th.Timer(0.10, Stream,args=(''))
class MainWindow:
    Transmit = False
    Lastline=0
    filename=""
    Started=False
    Connected=False
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_win = QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.main_win)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton_clicked)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.transmit_clicked)
        self.ui.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.OpenConn)

    def show(self):
        self.main_win.show()

    def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(
            initialdir="/", title="Select file", filetypes=(("txt files", "*.txt"), ("all files", "*.*")))
        print(filename)
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText(filename)

    def transmit_clicked(self):
        if not self.Connected:
            messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Error: No hay una conexion establecida')
            return
        if self.filename == "":
            messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Error: No ha seleccionado el archivo')
            return
        if (not self.Transmit):
            self.Transmit = True
            self.ui.pushButton_2.setText("Detener Streaming de datos")
            # iniciar transmicion de datos
            print(T.interval)
            if (not self.Started):
                T.start()
                self.Started=True
        else:
            self.Transmit = False
            self.ui.pushButton_2.setText("Iniciar Streaming de datos")

    def OpenConn(self):
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        self.Connected=True



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_win = MainWindow()
    main_win.show()
    import socket
    TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
    TCP_PORT = 5005
    BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    #s.setblocking(0)
    #conn, addr = s.accept()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved this by my self, it was more simple than i thougt i just needed to delcare two globals objects and done

```
class MainWindow:
    conn=socket.AF_INET
    addr=socket.SOCK_STREAM
```